# Highlight effect for a single line of text in a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highlighting

I want to recreate the effect shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFTrS/2/)

According to StackOverflow rules I apparently have to present some code if I link to jsfiddle.net, so here's the main function from that link. Although to see the effect you obviously have to follow the link instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".textWrapper").hover(function() {
    $(".highlight", this).show();
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
      var relativePos = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      var textRow = (Math.ceil(relativePos / 18) * 18) - 18;
      if (textRow >= 0) { $(".highlight", this).css("top", textRow + "px"); }
    });
  }, function() {
    $(".highlight", this).hide();
  });
});
```

Rather than highlight the text in yellow I'd prefer to change the color of the text itself.

I'd like the text to be light grey, and darken when highlighted, to bring that line into focus. This seems a lot more difficult than simply changing CSS, because the actual text properties do not change.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: the rules aren't just about posting "some code". You should post code you wrote in an attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: I see the problem with changing from highlight to text colour. I'm having a go at sorting it out.

Comment: @CFreak I appreciate that but since I have no idea where to start I haven't written any code yet

Comment: in your fiddle, there is a hidden div called highlight. it has a yellow background, an absolute position and the same width, as the lines in the text. on mouseover of a line, it gets moved to the hovered line and turns visible. that is the highlight effect. 
with this solution, you can't accomplish your goal, since you need to pick the text of the hovered line, wrap it inside a span and change the text color of the span... this is not the same as getting a cursor position and showing a 'yellow' box at this pos ;)

Comment: @errand: To tell the truth, the posted solution is far more easier and efficient :)

Comment: @aymericbeaumet: yeah, that's right. but the requirement seems to be, to change the hovered text color, not the background - so there is no "easy" option for this one. though, i'm not sure that i'm capable of solving it.

Comment: This is quite tricky to solve, especially considering window resizing.

Comment: I thought about surrounding the text with a span but the problem is, how do you figure out where that text begins and ends? Qhat makes this more complicated is the eventual target is a contentEditable div, so the text is subject to change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/5nxr6my4/

Using the same principle I created 2 white opaque `div`s `#highTop` and `#highBot` in order to overlay the text when the mouse pointer hovers over it. Their `height` and `top` properties are adjusted to the pointer position, so underlying black text appears gray, except the line at which the mouse pointer points to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#highTop').css('height', $('.textWrapper').height()).show();

    $('.textWrapper').hover(function() {   
        $('#highBot').show();
        $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
           var relativePos = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
           var textRow = (Math.ceil(relativePos / 18) * 18) - 18;
           if (textRow >= 0) { 
              // change height of #hightTop to make it cover upper part of text
              $('#highTop').css('height', textRow + 'px'); 
              // change position and height of #highBot to make it cover lower part of text
              $('#highBot').css('height', $('.textWrapper').height() - 18 - textRow + "px")
                           .css('top', textRow + 18 + 'px');
           }
        });
    }, function() {
        // when the pointer goes out of the text, hide #highBot and make #highTop cover entire text
        $('#highTop').css('height', $('.textWrapper').height() + 'px');
        $('#highBot').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks sasha. Its a start, but I'm looking for the inverse of this. the highlighted text should be darker.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Nice one!

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a little research and it appears that the only way that this would become possible would be to put each line in a separate HTML tag.

The reason that it is not possible the way you want it, is that the `.highlight` div doesn't contain the text itself so you can only apply an overlay rather than editing the underneath text.

It might help to have a look at http://jsbin.com/ukaqu3/91 which is about only displaying certain lines of text.

Comment: Splitting each line into a separate tag would for sure facilitate the problem. However you would need to rewrite the DOM on each window resize.

Comment: what makes this more complicated is the eventual target is a contentEditable div, so the text will change

Comment: the jsbin link would be our start... but i'm off for now ;)